# Get Names of all Columns in Excel sheet in SpreadSheetLight

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheetlight

I'm trying to populate a combobox with the names of the columns in a spreadsheet.
I'm using the spreadsheetlight library. I can set the cell value using the following code where `A` refers to column name and `1` refers to row name. *(Am I right?)*

But how can I get the the name of all columns in all sheets?

```
SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();    
sl.SetCellValue("A1", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the last column index using `SLWorksheetStatistics`:

```
SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();
int endColumnIndex = stats.EndColumnIndex;
```

Then iterate through the columns:

```
var headers = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= endColumnIndex; i++){
    headers.Add(sl.GetCellValueAsString(1, i));
}
```

The following will print the values "foo" and "bar" from the column list:

```
var fileName = "test.xlsx";
var sl = new SLDocument(fileName);

foreach (var sheetName in sl.GetWorksheetNames())
{
    SLDocument sheet = new SLDocument(fileName, sheetName);
    sheet.SetCellValue("A1", "foo");
    sheet.SetCellValue("B1", "bar");

    SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sheet.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    int endColumnIndex = stats.EndColumnIndex;

    var headers = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= endColumnIndex; i++)
    {
        headers.Add(sheet.GetCellValueAsString(1, i));
    }

    foreach (var column in headers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(column);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Will check and get back.

Comment: I tried your code to populate a combox,but instead of returning the column names.. the combobox returns the name of the file..I populated the comboxbox like this `foreach (var column in headers)
            {


                comboBox1.Items.Add(column);
            }`

Comment: I've corrected `stats.EndowIndex` to `stats.EndColumnIndex` and added a solution which runs perfectly

Comment: Your code works perfectly.. but what about files with more than 1 worksheets?

Comment: @techno An SLDocument is a sheet, you'd need to have a `for` loop through each of the sheets and run the above code

Comment: How can I loop through the sheets within a work book? Please advice?

Comment: @tecno `foreach (var name in sl.GetWorksheetNames())`, but really that's a separate question, your initial question has been answered

Comment: Yes.but a spreadsheet will have more than one sheets usually.How clan I create a document from the spreadsheet name ?

Comment: @techo This should really be in another question which can then be answered, comments shouldn't be for extended discussions

Comment: Since most excel documents have more than 1 sheets,your current answer is not useful to me...unless you add details about iterating through the sheets.The code above does not work with files with more than 1 sheets.

Comment: @techno Again, that's not what you asked. Regardless, I've updated my answer, but I'd recommend updating your question with your new requirements