# Do i need to have office installed to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

Tags: .net, excel, dll, spreadsheet

I'm trying to develop a new app to process excel files.As far as i know -in order to use the Built in Excel Manipulation functionality i need to have Microsoft Office installed *(i'm i right)?*

Or can i just download the dll  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`,add a reference and make the solution work on every machine?

Comment: You don't need Excel or Excel Interop to process Excel files. Use a library like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). That's the very reason the `xlsx` format replaced `xls` 10 years ago - to allow programs to generate `xlsx` files without requiring Excel

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the info.Currently im using `spreadsheetlight` to access excel documents.But i'm having a hard time iterating through sheets .. can i solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885027/get-names-of-all-columns-in-excel-sheet-in-spreadsheetlight/ easily using EPPlus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You need Excel to be installed to use the Excel Manipulation feature with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`.

---

If you need to edit only `.xlsx` files, then you can use libraries like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). These libraries do NOT need Excel to be installed.

Comment: Or no, you don't need Excel at all. You can generate/manipulate Excel files with the Open XML SDK, libraries like EPPlus or, worst case, the Jet OLEDB Provider

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but the question was if you need Excel to use the `Interop` assembly...

Comment: Thanks .. which library you suggest to easily solve this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885027/get-names-of-all-columns-in-excel-sheet-in-spreadsheetlight/ .Currently im using spreadsheetlight .. it seems that there is no  straight forward way to meet my requirement using spreadsheetlight.

Answer (score 0):

Question TLDR: Yes. You need to have Excel installed or an exception will be thrown.